# Huge Data Load on Mybatis

Tags: jquery, spring, mybatis, ibatis

using the spring mvc mybatis stack I am trying to query all the images which is saved as blobs from the sqlServer database, then render the image, name, date as

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
   ....more rows...
</table>
```

with pagination and select how many items per page, sort by name dates etc..

now the biggest problem is the query takes about 20 mins to run.
obviously I can't wait until all the data selected from the database
then doing the rendering

I wonder what's the general approach in my case, would be nice if you guys can 
point me to some sample code, perhaps a nice jquery ui plugin I could use.
I am new to web dev sorry.

Comment: You store binary image data in a relational database? Is there a possibility to pull them out and store them on a filesystem?

Comment: hi simon its a 3rd party system, we don't own the code

Comment: So I guess you at least have to query for the data asynchronously. You may need some @ Controller in Spring either with @ ResponseBody or an MVC Technology like Thymeleaf.  Also you will need AJAX-methods from jQuery, like .get (). Try to search in this direction

Comment: My best guess is it is mybatis that takes huge time to execute query and fetch records. Nothing related to jquery or anything else. Can you share  complete tag for a query i.e. how you have written in mybatis mapper xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="getUsers" parameterType="java.util.Map" fetchSize="1000" resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap" >
           select * from users;
<select>
```

My guess is you are not using `fetchSize` due to which the query takes 20 mins to execute as if there is no `fetchSize mybatis` will `read data one after another` which will consume time. But for example here I have defined `fetchSize` to `1000` which means it will get data in `batches i.e. now more` faster than what it used to be. You can set it to more than 1000 based upon your requirement and server's hardware set up.